# Set a _layouts page as homepage in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Currently I'm working on this project to create a SharePoint projects portal, but the context doesn't really matter. The problem is, all of my pages are custom Application Pages, and therefor reside in the _layouts folder. I'd like one of these pages (http://[servername]/[projectname]/_layouts/Pages/Summary/Default.aspx) to be shown whenever a user visits http://[servername]/[projectname].

After searching SP itself, the designer and Google, I couldn't seem to find a solution. I thought... let's try StackOverflow :-) Is it possible to let a _layouts page act as a homepage of a SP site?

Comment: Two questions. 1. Is redirection from the homepage an option? 2. Can the contents of your Summary/Default.aspx be placed on your homepage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot set page (http://[servername]/[projectname]/_layouts/Pages/Summary/Default.aspx) to website welcome page because this page not the part of our current site.

You can set a page to web site welcome page that has the part of our current website. To do this you have to go Site Actions->Site Settings-> Welcome Page (under Look and Feel), set your page as welcome page that has the part of our site. For this you have enabled publishing feature on site.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid "this site" check from code.

```
SPFolder rootFolder = web.RootFolder;
rootFolder.Properties["vti_welcomepage"] = "any URL in layouts folder";
rootFolder.Update();``
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do it.
I just tested in SharePoint 2013 Foundation.
It's a workaround but it works.

Steps:

1-In web.config allow server side code as follows:

```
<PageParserPaths>
        <PageParserPath VirtualPath="/*" CompilationMode="Always" 
            AllowServerSideScript="true" />
</PageParserPaths>
```

2-Create a site page and set it as home page (use SharePoint Designer)

3-Edit html code of your site page (the one created in step 2) by including server side code as follows:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("http://sp-2013/_layouts/15/SharePointProject3_SearchApplicationPage/search.aspx");
    }
</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```